# My system administrator set up a master-master replication for MYSQL (2 databases)

Tags: mysql

All tables are "synced". Are the permissions/users synced?

More specifically, what is "synced" and what is not??

Comment: Why don't you just ask your sysadmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assuming your sysadmin did not explicitly filter them out.  They're sync'd as part of the "mysql" database.